# Jenkins setup for running Selenium test on Ubuntu

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I already tried a lot for Jenkins setup on Ubuntu for running selenium test cases. But each time i face problem Like Display error , chrome connection timeout. I tried all the solution on internet (debugging this from last one week). Someone please help in setting up by step by step process (including version compatibility).

Also, test-cases on Ubuntu Jenkins run only on display mode?

Comment: can you provide more info about the docker settings, jenkins settings and selenium settings

Comment: Sorry for incomplete question , i am not using docker ,will only run Selenium cases from maven build and testng.

Comment: ok, I think you should look into headless chrome topic for the selenium test

Comment: Is it not possible to run without docker ?Jenkins on Ubuntu run only on headless ?

Comment: You can accomplish this without Docker, but I would still recommend investing some time in going the Docker route. Two options to make it easier to get started are https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium (which I use and like a lot) and https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid (which I haven't yet used, but hear good things about). To install Docker on Ubuntu, here's a useful reference: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/